# Sharing multiple files with Gluon ShareService (image and txt)

Tags: java, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

We want to know how we can share multiple files (image and txt file) with the Gluon ShareService. Especially how to share an image which was previously taken and stored (in gallery) with the PictureService.

But we need to create a file first with the path and image name. Unfortunately, the PictureService saves the image with the image title consisting of date and time at the moment the picture was taken.

We tried to get the image name with the loadImageFromGallery method but this returns void and opens the recent-screen.

Here what we've tried to share an image:

```
public void sharePicture() {
    Services.get(PicturesService.class).ifPresent(picturesService -> {
          Image image = picturesService.loadImageFromGallery().get();
      File file= new File("Pictures", image.toString());
      Services.get(ShareService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
        service.share("image/jpg", file);
      });
    });
  }
```

- How can we store the image where we want with a title we want?
- How can we share a file and an image together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track, combining different services from [Charm Down](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down), in order to select an image from the gallery and share it.

There is a major problem in this approach, though: You can't convert easily a JavaFX `Image` into a `File`.

So far the [PicturesService](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.4.1/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/PicturesService.html) returns only a JavaFX Image, and not a File, so we need a way to save that image into a file that we can read and share.

And the process is not easy since on mobile we don't have `SwingUtilities`.

The initial approach of using a `PixelReader` to read the image and get a byte array doesn't really work, as it will give you a big raw file that can't be read or share.

I've used this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28221613/3956070) that makes use of a PNG encoder to get the byte array of a png from a JavaFX image:

```
PngEncoderFX encoder = new PngEncoderFX(image, true);
byte[] bytes = encoder.pngEncode();
```

Then I'll save that byte array into a file in the public storage folder (so it can be shared), that I can retrieve using the `StorageService:

```
private File getImageFile(Image image) {
    if (image == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // 1. Encode image to png
    PngEncoderFX encoder = new PngEncoderFX(image, true);
    byte[] bytes = encoder.pngEncode();

    // 2.Write byte array to a file in public storage 
    File root = Services.get(StorageService.class)
            .flatMap(storage -> storage.getPublicStorage("Pictures"))
            .orElse(null);
    if (root != null) {
        File file = new File(root, "Image-" + LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd-HHmmss")) + ".png");
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            fos.write(bytes);
            return file;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now, you can call the `PicturesService`, retrieve the image, save it to the file and finally [share](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.4.1/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/ShareService.html) it:

```
Services.get(PicturesService.class).ifPresent(pictures -> {
    // 1. Retrieve picture from gallery
    pictures.loadImageFromGallery().ifPresent(image -> {
        // 2. Convert image to file
        File imageFile = getImageFile(image);

        // 3. Share file
        if (imageFile != null) {
            Services.get(ShareService.class).ifPresent(share -> {
                share.share("image/png", imageFile);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Note that you may run into memory issues if you try to encode big images.

Anyway, all the process could be simplified if the PicturesService will return a file in the first place. If you want to file an issue, you can do it [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/issues?status=new&status=open).

**EDIT**

A possible solution to avoid memory issues, and to reduce the size of the shared file, and based on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35613669/3956070), is scaling down the original image, if it exceeds certain size, like it is already done in the iOS implementation of the PicturesService:

```
private Image scaleImage(Image source) {
    // Possible limit based on memory limitations
    double maxResolution = 1280; 

    double width = source.getWidth();
    double height = source.getHeight();
    double targetWidth = width;
    double targetHeight = height;
    if (width > maxResolution || height > maxResolution) {
        double  ratio = width/height;
        if (ratio > 1) {
            targetWidth = maxResolution;
            targetHeight = targetWidth/ ratio;
        }
        else {
            targetHeight = maxResolution;
            targetWidth = targetHeight * ratio;
        }
    }

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(source);
    imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    imageView.setFitWidth(targetWidth);
    imageView.setFitHeight(targetHeight);
    return imageView.snapshot(null, null);
}
```

This method can be used now in `getImageFile()`:

```
    // 1 Scale image to avoid memory issues
    Image scaledImage = scaleImage(image);

    // 2. Encode image to png
    PngEncoderFX encoder = new PngEncoderFX(scaledImage, true);
    byte[] bytes = encoder.pngEncode();

    // 3. Write byte array to a file in public storage 
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Storing and sharing the image works now fine.

But we still have difficulties with sharing multiple files at once (a txt and jpg file). Do you have an solution for that as well? A zip would be fine too.

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: PicturesService only allows one selection at a time. So with that in mind you can do it in two steps: first, select images and store them in the public storage folder, but without sharing. Then when the user has selected all the images, use a share button. Since you have the images you can make a [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15970455/3956070) with them and finally share it.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer!
We decided to use a zip file for sharing all the pictures

Comment: Dear José, do you know by any chance, if your suggested implementation of PngEncoderFX is used in the new Gluon version 5? :-)

Comment: Gluon Mobile doesn’t use it, but check the PicturesService in Charm Down 3.8.0, it includes new API.

Comment: We checked it out, but it did not change much for us anyways. The pictures taken were still bigger than we wanted them to be; Gluon seems to take the raw footage (no scaled down version at all), so the app gets slow very fast

Comment: Do you have memory issues using files instead of images?

Comment: Yes, as well. We load a lot of pictures from files and also store our taken images in files...
Or maybe I have misunderstood your question. Could you please clearify? :)

Comment: You can get the image file from the service with [getImageFile](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.0/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/PicturesService.html#getImageFile--), so you don't have to do image processing.